# Vim changing the text objects of " in a single line with less number of keystrokes?

Tags: cursor-motions

Consider this situation, which I often follow in python and **consider that my cursor is on the letter *a* of *args*:**

```
args = ap.add_argument("-i", "--texture", type = str, required=True, help="path of the texture vector")
```

My objective is to change above line to this:

```
args = ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", type = str, required=True, help="path of the output")
```

Now if I have to change all the text objects in this line {"-i", "--texture", "path of the texture vector"). I do this:

```
ci" [ to change "-i" to "-o"]
Esc
2f"
ci" [ to change the second text object]
Esc
2f"
ci" [ then change the last text object]
Esc
```

It is bit clumsy to do `2f"` between every `ci"`, what are the more faster and smoother ways of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean `2;` (or simply `;;`)?

Comment: Yes it is more smooth! Is it possible to have something similar for the `ci"` ?

Comment: Use "dot"-operator whenever you can. Otherwise, `ci"` looks short enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be hard to get manually entered keys much shorter than you guys got it in comments. But if you use a mapping you can repeat the "jump to quotes and enter insert" action easily...

```
nnoremap XX 2f"ci"
```

(Replace XX with desired key combo.)

Then you just do `XX`, type in some text, `<esc>XX`, type in some text, `<esc>XX`, ... until you've changed all quoted strings in the line.

Comment: or double it up with `imap XX <Esc>XX` for an even faster sequence.